# Chained Arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const fetch = url => dispatch => {
  // ...
}

export const fetchQuestions = tag => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch(fetch(tag));
};
```

What is `dispatch` in the `fetch` function ? `url` is a first and single parameter `fetch` function. But what is `dispatch` here ?

Comment: It's called currying. Google it.

Comment: You can see it in action. There are some es6 => es5 converters online. Try this one for example: https://es6console.com/. Paste your code in the editor and click on "Transform"

Comment: Was going to downvote this based on your rep, but I realize you're not as involved with JavaScript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is equivalent to one function returning another. I.e. this

```
const fetch = url => dispatch => {
    // ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
const fetch = function(url) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

---

Similarly this

```
export const fetchQuestions = tag => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch(fetch(tag));
};
```

is equivalent to

```
export const fetchQuestions = function(tag) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return dispatch(fetch(tag));
    }
};
```

Comment: Why would you need to nest functions like this?

Answer (score 2):

`dispatch` is the first and single parameter of the function returned by the `url => ...` function. With normal function syntax, it would be

```
const fetch = function(url) {
    return function(dispatch) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a shorter way of writing a function that `returns another function`. The arguments `url` and `dispatch` are arguments to the **[curryed function](https://medium.com/@kevincennis/currying-in-javascript-c66080543528)** The ES5 equivalent of arrow function syntax would be

```
function fetch(url) {
    return function(dispatch) {
         ....
    }
}
```

or with Arrow syntax as

```
const fetch = (url) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Similarly you would have `fetchQuestion` written as

```
export function fetchQuestions(tag) {
     return function(dispatch){
            return dispatch(fetch(tag));
     }
}
```

or with Arrow syntax as

```
export const fetchQuestions = (tag) => {
    return (dispatch) =>  {
        return dispatch(fetch(tag));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is a **named** function expression that takes a `url` parameter and returns a new function that takes a `dispatch` parameter.

You could rewrite using traditional function syntax:

```
const fetch = function (url) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    // ...
  }
}
```