# Flow of arrow function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, arrow-functions

I am new to redux with react.I don't know why below code contains 2 arrow function and the purpose of it.

```
export const loadName = () => (dispatch: any) => {
    const name = localStorage.getItem('name'); 
    dispatch(setName(name));
}
```

Comment: I think loadName is function without parameter which returns a function which accepts dispatch as parameter and its body is  {
      const name = localStorage.getItem('name'); 
  dispatch(setName(name));
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax of arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147227/syntax-of-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's a function returning another function, equivalent to:

```
export const loadName = () => {
  return (dispatch: any) => {
    const name = localStorage.getItem('name'); 
    dispatch(setName(name));
  };
};
```

Comment: We can do without arrow function within arrow function means with simple one arrow function. But why we use this.

Comment: No real reason since it's not using `this` I think -- it's just shorter to use an arrow instead of writing `function`, and allows you to write it in one line